# Network file transfer speed reduced after 20H2 update

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, router

I am using 2 PCs in my home network. PC1 is the main PC and PC2 is a mini PC to operate 5 different external HDDs for network. 2 weeks ago, I had a network file transfer about 65-75 MB/s between 2 of them. After updating both PCs to 20H2, my file transfer speed reduced to 20-25MB/s.

The configuration and connections of the PCs are:

- PC1: wifi, 5ghz, 160mhz, 1.3-1.7 gbit/s
- PC2: lan, 1 gbit/s (cat6 cable)

There is no additional powerline or router so simply; PC1 (wifi) - router - PC2 (lan)

On both PCs;

- windows defender and firewall disabled
- netbios is enabled
- tcp autotune disabled
- large send offload disabled

both PCs network card drivers are the latest drivers

I did not make any changes last couple of months. So the only change was the windows update. That’s why I think that the update broke something but I could not find what it is.

Does anybody have an idea what the issue could be?

Ps: previous installation files were deleted so I can’t go back to 2004 version.

Update on further investigation:
Iperf3 parallel bandwidth test shows that my bandwidth between 2 PC is around 450-500mbit/s. Also I have 250mbit internet and if I download a file, I can able to download it around 33mb/s. I don’t think there is a problem with router or PC2 (lan connection). I guess there is a problem with my PC1’s WiFi connection which limits the file transfer.

Comment: What happens if instead of using Wifi, you stick an ethernet cable in PC1?

Comment: It is around 80mb/s.

Comment: Yeah, then Wifi could be a problem. Are there any physical obstructions between the AP and your PC, and what is the distance? Do you have neighbors with interfering networks? Could you try with a different device? Or update the network drivers on your PC?

Comment: The drivers are the latest. The distance between router to PC is about 3-4m and they are in the same room. I checked the wireless signals around the PC1 and yes there are some but in a different channel. So channels are not duplicated. 

I am wondering that I had totally normal speeds 2-3weeks ago. I have everything same except windows versions. Is it normal that speed slowed dramatically to 30% only because of the windows version?

Comment: If I can find another device with 5ghz, 160mhz wifi connection, I will try it immediately.